# Where is the to declare the ImageObject format in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, slideshow

In order to crate an Image Slider like here, I have to load the images from somewhere but unfortunately I'm not sure in which file (maybe component.ts?) I have to declare

```
imageObject: Array<object> = [{
    image: 'assets/img/slider/1.jpg',
    thumbImage: 'assets/img/slider/1_min.jpeg',
    alt: 'alt of image',
    title: 'title of image'
}, {
    image: '.../iOe/xHHf4nf8AE75h3j1x64ZmZ//Z==', // Support base64 image
    thumbImage: '.../iOe/xHHf4nf8AE75h3j1x64ZmZ//Z==', // Support base64 image
    title: 'Image title', //Optional: You can use this key if want to show image with title
    alt: 'Image alt' //Optional: You can use this key if want to show image with alt
}
];
```

and also where (how should the function look like). The component where I want to implement the slideshow is named Carousel and looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'carousel',
  templateUrl: './carousel.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carousel.component.scss', '../profile.scss']
})
export class Carousel implements OnInit {
   ngOnInit(): void {

}
```

Should I declare the image object in OnInit?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. You can create it in the `ngOnInit` function, so the object can be created when the component is instantiated.

To make it cleaner, you can create a function that creates the `imageObject` and call it inside the `ngOnInit` function.